# Is asp.net mvc still a separate download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net 3.5 sp1 installed, using vs.net 2008.

Is asp.net mvc still a separate downlaod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is a separate package. It's final version was released a long time after Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC team does have a goal of [getting MVC 2.0 into Visual Studio 2010](http://www.haacked.com/archive/2009/07/30/asp.net-mvc-released.aspx). Neither version is in the current beta though (or at least I couldn't find it).

Comment: @swilliams: Phil Haack explains the lack of MVC 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010 here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/09/aspnetmvc-vs10beta1-roadmap.aspx *When VS10 Beta 2 comes out, you won’t need to download a separate standalone installer to get ASP.NET MVC*